# jQuery change page and show tab on menu entry click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var tab = null;
var menuSelector = null;
jQuery(function ($) {
    console.log('test');
    //howtos tab
function changeMenuSelector() {
if ($( document ).width() > 967) {
    menuSelector = 'top-menu-nav';
} else {
 menuSelector = 'mobile_menu';
}
}
changeMenuSelector();
$( window ).resize(function() {
changeMenuSelector();
});

    $('#'+menuSelector+' a[href*="howtos"]').on('click', function(event){
      var e = event;
      var $ = jQuery;
      setTimeout(function () {
      e.preventDefault();
       console.log('pluto');
        window.localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_0');
       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1)
           {
                window.location.href='http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
           } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();
              window.localStorage.removeItem('tab');
           }
    },1000);}); 

    $('#'+menuSelector +' a[href*="projects"]').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('pluto');
        localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_1');
       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1)
           {
                window.location.href='http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
           } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();
              localStorage.removeItem('tab');
           }
    });

$('#'+menuSelector +' a[href*="reviews"]').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('pluto');
        localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_2');
       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1)
           {
                window.location.href='http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
           } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();
              localStorage.removeItem('tab');
           }
    });

$('#'+menuSelector +' a[href*="elearning"]').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('pluto');
        localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_3');
       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1)
           {
                window.location.href='http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
           } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();
              localStorage.removeItem('tab');
           }
    });

   $('#'+menuSelector +' a[href*="others"]').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('pluto');
        localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_4');


       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1)
           {
                window.location.href='http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
           } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();
              localStorage.removeItem('tab');
           }
    });


        if (!!localStorage.getItem('tab')) {
         tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
        console.log(tab);
        setTimeout(function(){$("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();}, 1)
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.et_pb_module.et_pb_tabs.et_pb_tabs_0').offset().top }, 
            1000);
         localStorage.removeItem('tab');
        }   

});
```

I have created a script to show tabs in Divi when you click on a menu entry. Divi does not use ids and hrefs for this, so I had to use a script.

The problem that I am facing is that this script that I made does not work with Divi's mobile menu.
I checked if menuSelector changed properly and if changeMenuSelector got executed as expected.
Furthermore, $('#'+menuSelector+' a[href*="howtos"]').length returns 1 in console and if I run $('#'+menuSelector+' a[href*="howtos"]')[0] in console I obtain the expected DOM element whehter I have the browser window sized for mobile or for desktop devices.

I also tried using setTimeout in case the issue was that it needed some time to accomplish an earlier action without any luck.

Therefore, is there anyone that could tell me why this does not work when the website is running in mobile mode?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by refactoring the code like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  console.log('test');
  var tab = null;
  var menuSelector = null;
  var guard = false;
  function changeMenuSelector() {
    if ($(document).width() > 967) {
      menuSelector = 'top-menu-nav';
      guard = false;
      initEventListeners(guard);
    } else {
      menuSelector = 'mobile_menu';
      guard = true;
      initEventListeners(guard);
    }
  }

  function initEventListeners(guard) {
    var localGuard = null;
    if (localGuard != guard) {
      var hrefs = ['howtos', 'projects', 'reviews', 'elearning', 'others'];
      hrefs.forEach(
        function (element, index, array) {
          $('#' + menuSelector + ' a[href*="' + element + '"]').off();
          console.log(element);
          $('#' + menuSelector + ' a[href*="' + element + '"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('pluto');
            window.localStorage.setItem('tab', 'et_pb_tab_' + index);
            if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('blog-posts') === -1) {
              window.location.href = 'http://www.davidepugliese.com/blog-posts/';
            } else {
              tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
              $("li." + tab + ">a")[0].click();
              $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.et_pb_module.et_pb_tabs.et_pb_tabs_0').offset().top },
                1000);
              window.localStorage.removeItem('tab');
            }
          });
        });
      localGuard = guard;
    }
  }


  changeMenuSelector();
  initEventListeners();

  $(window).resize(function () {
    changeMenuSelector();

  });

  if (!!localStorage.getItem('tab')) {
    tab = localStorage.getItem('tab');
    console.log(tab);
    setTimeout(function(){$("li."+tab+">a")[0].click();}, 1)
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.et_pb_module.et_pb_tabs.et_pb_tabs_0').offset().top },
      1000);
    localStorage.removeItem('tab');
  }
});
```